# Minimum of a function defined by an integral

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

I have a problem with  the minimum.
Let:

$G(y)=\int_{y}^{a}g(x)dx$ , $g>0$ , $0\leq y< a$.

Is that the function $G(y)$ different to zero?
Is that the function $G(y)$ admits a muinmum different to zero?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $G(a) = \int _a ^a g(x) \ \Bbb d x = 0$. Notice also that $G'(y) = -g(y) < 0$, which shows that $G : [0,a] \to \Bbb R$ is *strictly* decreasing, therefore $G(y) > G(a) = 0$ for all $0 \le y < a$, which shows that $G > 0$ on $[0,a)$. In particular, since $G$ is decreasing, it follows that its minimum is $G(a) = 0$.

Comment: Then, there is not a lower bound $m$ different  to zero such that:
$G(y)>m$ for all  $0\leq y <a $.

Comment: @user326064: Exactly.

Comment: Let f a positive function such that $f>0$ for $y>a$ and $f(a)=0$ and let $I(x)$= $\int_{a}^{x}f(y)dy$ for $x $belongs to $ \left [ a,b \right ]$.
Is that the function I(x) different to zero? Is that the function I(x) admits a minimum different to zero?